# Регулярное выражение, которое матчит определенный номер

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходима регулярка, которая матчит номера договоров формата 7100 1234567
Между 7100 и семью цифрами может быть пробел, нецифровой символ (№ или N) или слитное написание (71001234567)

```
[\s]?(7100[\s|\D]\d{7})[\s]
```

С первыми двумя условиями (пробел и нецифровой символ) проблем нет. Что добавить в выражение, чтобы вылавливало номера написанные слитно (71001234567) ???

Comment: Может, `^\s*7100\D\d{7}\s*$`? Я так понимаю, могут быть пробелы в начале и конце строки, да?

Comment: `[\s]?(7100[\s|\D]?\d{7})[\s]` или `[\s]?(7100[^\d]?\d{7})[\s]`. https://regex101.com/r/qTLpbG/1

Comment: Кстати, что значит "вылавливало"? Вы ищете эти номера в каком-то большем тексте? Тогда `(?<!\S)7100\D\d{7}(?!\S)` может сработать.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, да. использую регулярки для написания политик DLP систем. В начале и в конце строки могут быть пробелы.

Comment: Akina,  [^\d] означает любой символ, кроме цифрового?

Comment: `\D` находит  любой символ, кроме цифрового. `[^\d]` тоже, но не во всех библиотеках регулярных выражений. Т.е. если у вас POSIX-совместимый движок, используйте `[^0-9]`. `7100[^0-9]?[0-9]{7}`

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста. Номер матчится, только если стоит пробел или перевод на новую строку. Как сделать, чтобы был матчинг без пробела или новой строки. https://regex101.com/r/OODs8F/1

Comment: `(?<!\S)7100\D?\d{7}(?!\S)`, https://regex101.com/r/OODs8F/2. Возможно, у вас нет поддержки блоков просмотра назад, тогда попробуйте `(?:^|\s)(7100\D?\d{7})(?:$|\s)` или - лучше - `(?:^|\s)(7100\D?\d{7})(?!\S)` (я не уверен, что `(?:^|\s)` необходим)

Comment: ?:^  для чего это, не могу понять...

Comment: Это незахватываемая подмаска, она не хранит найденный текст в отдельном буфере памяти.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, знать, что у вас сработало. Тогда можно будет дать нормальный, полноценный ответ.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew, немного проблемно предоставить какие-либо результаты. Существует политика в DLP системе, которая выявляет номера телефонов в письмах сотрудников. Однако, кроме номеров сотрудники пересылают номера полисов формата 7100 1234567. Как Вы можете видеть формат номера полиса схож с номером телефона. Регулярное выражение, которое я запросил, используется в качестве правила-исключения. Благодаря этому исключению DLP система не будет выявлять те письма, в которых есть номер полиса. В любом случае, благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var strings = [
  "7100 1234567 xyz",
  "abc 7100 1234567 xyz",
  "abc 71001234567 xyz",
  "abc 7100N1234567 xyz",
  "abc 7100№1234567 xyz",
  "abc 7100NN1234567 xyz",
  "1234567100 1234567 xyz"
],
re = /(?:^| )(7100(?:N| |№)?[0-9]{7})/i;
strings.forEach(function(str) {
    console.log(str + " : " + str.match(re));
});
```

Comment: Вроде лишнее находит: https://regex101.com/r/Qa6dTf/1

Comment: @roman147 у автора в регулярке на первом месте стоит `[\s]?` что означает 0 или 1 раз. Поэтому я его проигнорировал.

Comment: @roman147 поправил

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/6TVkMM/1 Еще не вполне корректно.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b7100( |№|N|)\d{7}\b
```

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/ss1k8X/2).

Проверено на работу в тексте.